# Table header overlaps with content in Chrome print preview

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, pdf

We have a HTML page with `<table>` element. When we print the page and save it as a PDF document in Chrome 115.0.5790.110 64-bit in A3 format, the table header overlaps with the content on the 2nd page.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Save this HTML code as `table.html` document on your PC: https://pastebin.com/hGhy42EM *(code is too long to fit in the question - number of characters is exceeded)*
2. Open `table.html` document with Chrome 115.0.5790.110 64-bit
3. Press `Ctrl+P` to open the print dialogue. Select "Save as PDF" and choose A3 format.

This is how the 2nd page looks like in the print preview:

[image]

Comment: I can confirm that I see this problem on Windows 11. Even after I make your HTML into a valid HTML page. There are no obvious errors in the HTML table. However, Firefox "prints" it correctly. This seems a bug in the PDF code of the WebKit family of browsers because Brave (another WebKit browser) has exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is there for me on Chrome (and Edge) Windows10.

I do not have an explanation - apart from 'it looks like a bug'.

However, here is a workaround.

It appears to be related to the default margin setting. Go down the print options to the margin settings and select 'customize'. At first I set the margin to 11mm (from the 10mm already there) and then the print preview was fine.

Next time I didn't change anything, just selected 'customize' and the print preview was fine.

Comment: This tricks works for my Chrome. It does indeed look like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

There is no bug; it's working perfectly here in Edge (Chromium based). CSS can be tricky for PDF, but you simply need to add the PDF printer styling. Since for a PDF layout the Media Page size must be defined first. Then you can work from that.

```
<style>
@media print { @page { margin: 0; size: 297mm 421mm ; } body { margin: 0; } }
  * {
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
...
```

[image]

I see you are trying to be borderless but as it stands your Media is only fitting to 417mm/421mm which is a different scalar challenge:

[image]

The Html layout for print versus screen should be detailed here ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries#syntax

### Later note

The use of @media print @page size may be needed when headless printing can default to a different page layout than expected.

Comment: That's interesting - I'd not heard that for a pdf it won't pick up the required page size from the printer settings (I've never bothered to set it in the code). Is there a reference for that?

Comment: While you can use @page to modify the printed page dimensions, I have found no reference which says you have to. I would much rather not as the end user may have a different requirement for size than one built into the code.

Comment: I agree that a pdf writer would need to know the page size but in all the other cases of paper size I've tried (Chrome/Edge) e.g. A4, letter etc, the pdf adapts to the paper size I set at the print level. I did not have to define it in the CSS. So I do think there is something wrong with the treatment of A3. And I don't think in general it is either necessary (and it's certainly not desirable) to have to set the paper sizes by CSS for general cases.

Comment: Yes, that’s why I wouldn’t want to put the paper size into the code but let the user decide at the point they are printing so when the pdf actually get physically printed it’s right for them.